# NoClassDefError com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client

Tags: java, android, jersey

I am writing a API to get data from my webservices. I am using the jersey client api to consume my web services. The problem is when I run the application I am getting this error:

```
 10-22 19:44:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(13171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-22 19:44:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(13171): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
 10-22 19:44:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):   at com.ppsjamaica.data.DataManager.getAllUser(DataManager.java:54)
 10-22 19:44:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):   at com.ppsjamaica.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
 10-22 19:44:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
```

I don't have a clue what the problem is. Here is the class that invokes the Client class:

```
public class DataManager {
public Client client;

public DataManager ()
{
    client = Client.create();
}


public List <User> getAllUser ()
{
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(URL.URL_USERS_ALL);
    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);

    if (response.getStatus () == 200)
    {
        return response.getEntity (new GenericType<List <User>> (){});
    }
    else
        return null;
}//end getAllUser method
```

}

Comment: Are you sure Jersey is supported in Android? Did you provide the library jar?

Comment: I'm not sure if android supports it and yeah I added jersey jars to the project build path as a user library

Comment: do you have other jars in the project that work? or is the problem this one specificly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an internal Sun/Oracle API and is not available in Android. Jersey or whatever library you are using shouldn't be using it in the first place. File a bug with them or find another library.